# Difference Between Azure App Registrations Blades

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I've noticed that I can access the App Registrations blade directly in the Azure Portal, or I can access it through the Active Directory blade.  Is there any difference here?  I see the same applications under both "All" and "Owned," but I'd like to know if there would be any difference in the result, were I to add/edit registrations in one place versus the other.  For reference, here are screenshots of both contexts:

**Outside of AD:**
[image: App Registrations outside of AD]

**Within AD:**
[image: App Registrations within AD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. Basically the one you called "Outside AD" is just a shortcut.

The same applies to **Enterprise applications**. You can find it inside the **Active Directory** blade or accessing **All services** > **Enterprise applications**

Comment: I am left pretty curious, then, what the App Registration blade's appearance and capabilities are if the account has no AD set up.  In any case, thanks!

Comment: Can you access the Azure Portal without an AD?